# Progress 4GL: Exporting XML into JSON using temp-tables

Tags: json, xml, temp-tables, openedge, progress-4gl

im trying to convert XML file into JSON using temp-tables. I can take every data out of my XML and save it, but i also take additional relation field which is not necessary for me. I might be blind but i dont see the solution for that.

OUTPUT (json):

```
 {"employees": {   
"employee": [
     {
       "relation_id": null,
       "id": 1,
       "firstname": "aaa",
       "lastname": "bbb",
       "role": 1,
       "photo": "smile.jpg"
     },
     {
      "relation_id": null,
       "id": 2,
       "firstname": "ccc",
       "lastname": "ddd",
       "role": 1,
       "photo": "smile.jpg"
     },
     {
       "relation_id": null,
       "id": 3,
       "firstname": "www",
       "lastname": "bbb",
       "role": 0,
       "photo": "smile.jpg"
     },
     {
       "relation_id": null,
       "id": 4,
       "firstname": "kkk",
       "lastname": "sdfsdf",
       "role": 2,
       "photo": "smile.jpg"
     },
     {
       "relation_id": null,
       "id": 5,
       "firstname": "sdfsdf",
       "lastname": "gsdg",
       "role": 2,
       "photo": "smile.jpg"
     }   ],   "roles": [
     {
       "relation_id": null,
       "role": [
         {
           "relation_id": null,
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Actor"
         },
         {
           "relation_id": null,
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Student"
         }
       ]
     }   ] }}
```

So i want to delete all the "relation_id" field so my output is without them, but i need them to make relations between temp-tables to take all the data. Any ideas?

Here is my code.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE start AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE zapisz AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE typ AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE doPliku AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE wartosc AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE employee NO-UNDO XML-NODE-NAME "employee"
    FIELD relation_id AS RECID XML-NODE-TYPE "Hidden"
    FIELD id AS INTEGER
    FIELD firstname AS CHARACTER  
    FIELD lastname AS CHARACTER
    FIELD role AS INTEGER 
    FIELD photo AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE roles NO-UNDO XML-NODE-NAME "roles"
    FIELD relation_id AS RECID XML-NODE-TYPE "Hidden".

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE role NO-UNDO XML-NODE-NAME "role"
    FIELD relation_id AS RECID XML-NODE-TYPE "Hidden"
    FIELD id AS INTEGER
    FIELD name AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE DATASET employees
FOR employees, employee, roles, role
DATA-RELATION dr3 FOR roles, role RELATION-FIELDS(relation_id, relation_id) NESTED. 


start = DATASET employees:READ-XML("FILE","D:\USERS\DANIELH\zadanie testowe\relacje2_zmiana\testInputFile2.xml","APPEND", ?, ?, ?, ?).

    ASSIGN
  typ = "FILE"
  doPliku = "D:\USERS\DANIELH\Zadanie testowe\relacje2_zmiana\ZadanieeeWOW.json"
  wartosc  = TRUE.

zapisz = DATASET employees:WRITE-JSON(typ, doPliku, wartosc).
```

Comment: Post the XML you're reading from disk. Also: your code wont run. The temp-table employees is missing in the code. Also I guess you should have relations between employees -> employee -> roles? Perpahs that is dr1 and dr2?

Answer (score 3):

Set the fields you don't want in the json-file as `SERIALIZE-HIDDEN`. `XML-NODE-TYPE "Hidden"` only defines how they should be handled as xml, not as json.

`SERIALIZE-HIDDEN` however is for all serializing formats so you can remove `XML-NODE-TYPE = "Hidden"`.

Like this:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE employee NO-UNDO XML-NODE-NAME "employee"
    FIELD relation_id AS RECID SERIALIZE-HIDDEN
    FIELD id AS INTEGER
    FIELD firstname AS CHARACTER  
    FIELD lastname AS CHARACTER
    FIELD role AS INTEGER 
    FIELD photo AS CHARACTER.
```